# Cannot create a new Angular project on a Mac

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a new Angular project named 'test' on a Mac. When I use Terminal to create a new project using:

```
xxxx$ ng new test
```

I get the following error message:

```
 -bash: /Users/xxxx/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng: 
 No such file or directory
```

I used the following to install Angular:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I have the following software installed:

Visual Studio Code version 1.18.0

node version 9.1.0

npm version 5.5.1

Comment: type on CMD `ng --version` what is say

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

If it doesn't work: go manually to the `bin` folder, there suppose to be ng file which will be empty and delete it manually.
 
Then run `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling everything from scratch:

## make sure you have latest version of node and npm

node -v

npm -v

## clean up previous angular-cli installations

npm uninstall -g angular-cli

npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli

npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm cache clean

## install latest angular-cli

npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

ng new my-app

cd my-app

ng serve --open

Comment: npm cache clean gave me a warning: npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force. When I did that I received the message: npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing. After trying toi reinstall I received the message: npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command `sudo npm install -g angular-cli`

Comment: received the following error: xxxx is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.